# Excel - dynamic chart x axis - ignore x categories with no data

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, vba

I have a predefined list of x labels, e.g. months of the year.
I want to dynamically exclude some of these from my excel plot, e.g. if some of the y values are blank, zero or errors.

Things I've tried:

- If I use an (if data is bad, then change xlabel to blank or NA())
  process, excel still leaves a space for the blank or #N/A x label - see image. This is the second most upvoted answer to [Creating a chart in Excel that ignores #N/A or blank cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013911/creating-a-chart-in-excel-that-ignores-n-a-or-blank-cells), but doesn't quite do what I'm after... Unfortunately, there is no option for 'No Gaps' in the Hidden and Empty Cell Settings.

[image: If there is something wrong with the Y values (blank, non-numeric etc), I want to dynamically exclude the corresponding series from the chart]

- If I filter out rows where the Y values meet the reject condition, I get the chart I want, but the filter doesn't update automatically when the Y values get changed by a calculation elsewhere, ie its not dynamic. Pivot charts are the same.
- I can't get formulaic named ranges ([Excel charts - setting series end dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198045/excel-charts-setting-series-end-dynamically?rq=1))  to do what I want - the formula will return something like 'Jan, FALSE, Mar, Apr' rather than 'Jan, Mar, Apr', and we end up with the same problem as in the picture above.

Non-VBA solutions preferred  = )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buddy, seems Non-VBA solution is still to be found, as solution lies on hiding the said row.
However if you are bent on finding non-vba solution then here is very crude solution -
suppose this is the data (C3:I15) with the helper columns which has been described below -

[image]

- helper column (hC1) has formula

  =IF(ISNUMBER(D4),1,"")
- hC2 has formula

  =IFERROR(E4*ROW(),"")
- hC3 has formula

  =SMALL($F$4:$F$15,ROW()-3)

  - X has formula

  =IF(ISNUMBER(G4),INDEX(C4:C15,MATCH(G4,F4:F15,0)),"")

  - Y has formula

  =VLOOKUP(H4,C4:D15,2,FALSE)

drag down all the formulas after entering into first rows....

Now you can plot chart from continuous data -

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've almost got this working - is is possible to generalise this to allow for multiple consecutive blanks?

Comment: @arthuritus have edited the previous answer based on your suggestion to  generalise this allow it for multiple consecutive blanks

Comment: This solution appear to require changing the chart's source data range every time the number of "blank" categories changes. Not automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve posted anything here, but i found a solution for this, and it really really helped.

So the solution creates a X axis that is actually dynamic, and will "grow" as you add more numbers, automatically.

It uses "named ranges" (crt+f3) to stabilish ranges and you add those later in your graphic.
Check the link to see how it works.

[Link of the source][1]
[1]: https://exceljet.net/charts/dynamic-chart-ignore-empty-values

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).