# How do I dynamically reference headers in Excel

Tags: excel, charts

I am trying to use a table's header row for chart values in a dynamic manner. I have been trying to do this in various way but, I have thus far not been successful. I tried dynamic range, pivoting, and indirect, but I couldn't figure out how to use them for this objective.

I have a main sheet for the insertion of new performance statistics. The main sheet ("Metrics") has the following columns in a table:

A - Contains a metric name.

B - Contains the value for that metric, for the month January.

C - Same as "B", but February.
And so on.

The charts all have the X axis for the month, and Y axis(s) for the values.

The implementation for the the Y axis is not a problem, if I can get how to do the X axis. They will have the same implementation.

--

I have tried the following for a range, in the chart:

```
=OFFSET(Metrics!$B$2:$ZZ$2,0,0,1,1)

=Metrics!$B$2:$ZZ$2
```

I have also tried to create a pivot table from the source and use that, but I couldn't figure out how to go about it.

The results I got...
For the OFFSET, the formula was invalid
For the $B$2:$ZZ$2, the result is the chart was "flattened" to the left side.

Example Data:

Table: ("Metrics")

```
________| "Jan" | "Feb" | "Mar"
"Metric A"| Value | Value | Value
"Metric B"| Value | Value | Value
"Metric C"| Value | Value | Value
```

The required outcome is as follows:

A. For a chart to use row #1 (Jan, Feb...) for X-axis names (Just the names below the chart).
B. For the same chart to use one row (such as row #2) for the actual column/line values.
C. I need it to work in a dynamic way, so if I add a column "Apr" on the right of "Mar", the column automatically added to the chart as an X-axis name, and its values are likewise added as actual column/line values, making them part of the existing data.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and an example input and expected output.

Comment: Hope the addition helps.

Comment: you will find it a lot easier to arrange your data in columns where Month is in one column, Metrics in one column, Values in one column. You can then either create an excel table and have a pivottable and pivotchart off this which will update when you refresh the pivot, or create dynamic ranges that refer to each column and use these to plot on the chart. And everything you need to know to have a go yourself https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-build-dynamic-charts-in-excel/

Comment: And if that is not enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198045/excel-charts-setting-series-end-dynamically   or https://superuser.com/questions/208012/how-do-i-dynamically-change-a-charts-series-in-excel or ...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I thank you @QHarr for your help.

In the end, non of those were what was needed as an answer, but I have found the way.

I created, on a separate sheet called "PivotTable", a table based on cells with the following (and similar) formulas:

=INDEX(Metrics!$B$2:$ZZ$2,1,Metrics!A57,1)

"B2:ZZ2", had their numbers changed in each cell from left to right, to point to one column further to the right, so each time I pulled with them a range one cell further to the right.

"A57" and onward, I placed a list of numbers in cells starting at "1" in cell A57" of sheet "Metrics". Just to use for this formula.

Whenever I add a new **column** to the right of the original table in "Metrics" sheet, I can go over to my "PivotTable" sheet, and drag the last row for Excel's auto-complete to create the new row in the "pivoted table" with the proper values from the new column.

Then I went to my charts and based the formula for the values on the following:

=PivotTable!$B$2:$B$4

"B2:B4", these are the **cells** in the **column of the pivoted table** that I want to use for the particular chart column/line.

Whenever I use the auto-complete method mentioned above on the pivotted table, the chart will automatically be updated accordingly.

This is far less elegant than I would have liked, but it works well, and **most importantly(!)** requires little work from whomever needs to update the excel.
They just enter the values in the original table, and drag the row on the pivoted one.

--
Ziv.